# Back-filling tables from another table; cannot have duplicates

Tags: php, mysql

We have two tables on two different MySQL servers. We have a unique key, which is `invoice` and `date`.

We need to grab all of the records from a certain time period and put them into another table. The caveat is that there may be records that exist already so we want to exclude those from the records we are back-filling.

What queries, ideas, scripts, etc. would be the most helpful in accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2):

If you put a unique key onto a field that will uniquely identify a record (or a combination of fields), you can use INSERT IGNORE INTO as your MySQL statement. This will insert records, but if a key conflict arises (such as when that record already exists), it will simply proceed to the next record.

You could also use REPLACE INTO, instead of INSERT INTO, which is similar to INSERT IGNORE INTO, but rather than proceeding to the next record, it will overwrite the conflicted row.

Answer (score 0):

Look at merge syntax

[TSQLmerge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Try the answer from kingcoyote first +1

Comment: The question is tagged MySQL (not sure if by mod or asker), so TSQL may not be pertinent.  It does not appear that MySQL has a `MERGE` command.  Although, it looks like `REPLACE INTO`, as kingcoyote mentioned and I missed before commenting, might be a viable alternative: http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2010/05/14/mysql-replace-into/

Comment: @EricH I am pretty sure it came up on a TSQL search when I first looked.  Will go ahead and delete this after he accepts kingcoyote.